# Weblogic clustering - how unicast will result in more bandwidth consumption and less for multicast

Tags: weblogic, cluster-computing, multicast

I was reading [following](http://www.ateam-oracle.com/weblogic-server-cluster-messaging-protocols/) article, I am not able to understand how Unicast will require more bandwidth and network calls.

Suppose, I am having a multicast cluster having 4 nodes, now a message is to be replicated so node having the message will multicast it to the multicast address and then it will replicated to other cluster nodes.

Same thing in Unicast will have a leader of the cluster so node having message will transmit it to cluster leader and cluster leader will replicate it to remaining 2 nodes.

So, in both cases I see same bandwidth consumption and network calls.

Answer (score 1):

That web page really makes it clear in the **Considerations** section, but in summary:

- unicast sends one targeted update message, which is replicated a few times by each recipient until every server in the cluster is updated
- multicast sends a single message that *all* servers on the network subnet receive with no retransmit delays

So in the case of a 4-node cluster:

- Unicast will result in 1 message to group node + 2 messages to the member nodes = 3 total
- Multicast will result in 1 message to the subnet = 1 total

Comment: Thanks for inputs. Suppose 1 message has arrived at node1, now in case of unicast it will send to group leader and group leader will send to other 2 nodes - so total of 3 communication. In case of multicast, it will directly send to other 3 nodes, again total of 3 communication. How there is more bandwidth and n/w call in case of unicast??

Comment: BTW as per you which is better? As per me multicast.

Comment: You are incorrect in your multicast example. Only one message is sent, but is received by 3 other servers.

In general, multicast is better if your network topology supports it. It's a question best answered by your network engineers or cloud team, as everyone's setup is different.

Comment: For more info, perhaps this will help:

 http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/CLUST/features.htm#CLUST695